# Laravel 5 / After setting default website

Tags: php, laravel, web, phpstorm, setting

After setting the default website by the following command:

```
php -S localhost:8888 -t public
```

I can't use anymore my terminal without pressing Ctrl-C. Is there is a way to keep my default website active and continue using my terminal?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using PhpStorm, you can open another terminal tab.
Just click on the plus sign and you are ready to go.

There's **another approach** that is really cool, though.

1. In your settings, go to `Languages and Frameworks > PHP` and set the interpreter.
2. Close the settings, go to `Run > Edit Configurations...`, click on the plus sign, chose `PHP Built-in Web Server`.
3. Name it, set host to `localhost` and port to `8888` (or another one).
4. Chose your document root to be the `public` folder inside Laravel (`E:\xampp\htdocs\bb2015\public` in your case).
5. Save it and now you can run your WebServer easily and without relaying on the terminal.